# pandas perform multiple transformations and creating a new data frame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I have a daframe where I want to perform multiple (independent) transformations, and they create a new data frame (with a multi-index), where each index correspond to one of the transformations.

More concretely:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, "X", 'H', 100], [2, "Y", 'K', 100] ,[3, "X", 'H', 200], [4, "Y", 'H', 100]], columns=['id', 'XY', 'HK', 'A']).set_index("id")


    XY  HK  A
id          
1   X   H   100
2   Y   K   100
3   X   H   200
4   Y   H   100
```

I now want to know how many `XY` and how many `HK` have the same `A`. The final results should look like this (with multi-index):

```
     XY      HK
    X   Y   H   K   
A       
100 1.0 2.0 2.0 1.0
200 1.0 NaN 1.0 NaN
```

This is what I was expecting to work:

```
df.groupby(['A', 'XY', 'HK']).count()
```

but it only contains the multi index without the values.

What I was able to do is:

1. count the `XY`:

   ```
   xy_count = df.groupby(['A', 'XY']).count().HK.unstack()
   ```
2. count the `HK`:

   ```
   hk_count = df.groupby(['A', 'HK']).count().XY.unstack()
   ```
3. merge the results (?)

   ```
   results = pd.DataFrame()
   results['XY'] = xy_count
   results['HK'] = hk_count
   ```

but this last part does now work.

So my questions are:

Q1: There seems to be a better way I am missing
Q2: why does step 3 not work?

Not really a question, but also I find confusing that to get the HK, you have to call the XY column and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
groups = df.groupby('A')
pd.concat({col:groups[col].value_counts().unstack() 
           for col in ['XY','HK']}, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
      XY        HK     
       X    Y    H    K
A                      
100  1.0  2.0  2.0  1.0
200  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

I will do `melt` first

```
s=df.melt('A').groupby(['A','variable']).value.value_counts().unstack([1,2])
variable   HK        XY     
value       H    K    Y    X
A                           
100       2.0  1.0  2.0  1.0
200       1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0
```

Comment: Could you please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62069465/match-lists-and-get-value-of-one-column-based-on-values-of-other-columns-from-da using your good knowledge in pandas? Thanks